# Binding XAML control to Application Data file

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a service class that contains all the functionality for dealing with ApplicatonData

```
public class AppSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static volatile AppSettings _instance;

    private ApplicationDataContainer _localData;
    private ApplicationDataContainer _roamingData;
    private StorageFolder _localFolder;
    private StorageFolder _roamingFolder;

    ... 
    //Code to make AppSettings a singleton class. 
    //Using AppSettings.Instance to access public properties/methods
    ...

    private void SaveSettings(string key, object value, bool roaming = false)
    {
        if (roaming)
            _roamingData.Values[key] = value;
        else
            _localData.Values[key] = value;
    }

    private T ReadSetting<T>(string key, T defaultValue = default(T), bool roaming = false)
    {
        if (roaming)
        {
            if (_roamingData.Values.ContainsKey(key))
                return (T)_roamingData.Values[key];
        }
        else if (_localData.Values.ContainsKey(key))
            return (T)_localData.Values[key];

        return defaultValue;
    }

    public async void SaveToFile<T>(T obj, string propName, bool roaming = false)
    {
        StorageFile file = await (roaming ? _roamingFolder : _localFolder).CreateFileAsync(propName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
    }

    public async Task<T> LoadFromFile<T>(string propName, bool roaming = false)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await (roaming ? _roamingFolder : _localFolder).GetFileAsync(propName);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file, UnicodeEncoding.Utf8));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return default;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }


    //List all setting here
    public string exampleProp
    {
        get => ReadSetting<string>(nameof(exampleProp));
        set
        {
            SaveSettings(nameof(movie_staging_folder), value, false);
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    ... 
    // Other properties
    ...
}
```

This works fine for single value properties, like:

```
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind services:AppSettings.Instance.exampleProp, Mode=TwoWay}"
         ... />
```

My problem is binding to multi-value properties. I have a `ListView` that displays a list of user-chosen directories. I made `SaveToFile()` and `LoadFromFile()` to (de)serialize an object, an ObservableCollection in my case, and save/load it as a file in ApplicationData folder. I can't figure out how to bind this to the `ListView ItemsSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a property inside the ObservableCollection to receive the deserialized collection from LoadFromFile() and bind the property to the ItemsSource of the listView.

```
public AppSettings()
{
    InitializeMyList();​
}​

private async void InitializeMyList() 
{
    myLists = await LoadFromFile<ObservableCollection<String>>("");​
}
private ObservableCollection<string> myLists = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> MyLists 
{
    get {
        return myLists;
    }
    set {
            ......
    }
}
```

.xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind services:AppSettings.Instance.MyLists}"></ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you. It took me a bit to try this out, but it worked great. I overthink things a lot and get lost in my inexperience and have a hard time seeing, the now obvious, simple way of doing things.